# What is the expression for "high fever"?

Tags: word-usage, expression-choice

It can not be *high*/*low* according to my understanding.
Fever is fever.

> He is suffering from fever of high temperature.
>   He is suffering from high fever.

Comment: Assuming a fever is any temperature > 98.6, why can't 98.7 be a "low fever" and 103.9 be a "high fever"?

Comment: "High fever" is the common term (in the US), and would refer to a temp above, say 103F.  (Though the actual break point between "fever" and "high fever" is not codified anywhere that I know of.)

Comment: should be "a high fever"

Answer (score 4):

It is **not** wrong.

> A body temperature of 98.6 F (37 C) is baseline.  A fever is a higher-than-normal body temperature.

(and therefore can be known as a high fever or a high temperature)

Terms used to describe fever or fever types:

[*Low-grade*](http://www.emedicinehealth.com/fever_in_adults/article_em.htm) fevers range from about 100 F-101 F while [*high-grade*](http://www.emedicinehealth.com/fever_in_adults/article_em.htm) fevers range from about 103 F-104 F.  Extremely high fevers are also termed *hyperpyrexia.*

Consider these simple expressions:

- got (a) high fever/temperature.
- down with a fever.
- running a fever/temperature
- E.g. Jane can't go to school today. She's running a fever.

Answer (score 4):

"*Fever* is not *fever*" any more than "*depression* is *depression*."

One can suffer from mild, moderate or severe depression, episodic depression, etc.

With the ranges being disputed, fever can be low grade (*usually* between 99.9° to 101.4°), fever (101.5° - 104.5°), high fever (104°.6° - 106.4°) and *hyperpyrexia* - 106.5° and above, treated as a medical emergency. The only reason that it's *hyperpyrexia* instead of very high fever is because, well, writing very high fever as an admission diagnosis doesn't fly. If it's caused by a drug reaction or certain diseases, it's called *malignant hyperthermia*.

Rest assured that doctors respect these differences. Blood cultures are taken for high fever (lower if in the presence of immunocompromised status), and ice packs, /"cold blankets"/ wet sheets with fans, etc. for hyperpyrexia.

Similarly, a person can have grades of low temperature, called *hypothermia*.

Comment: Why the quotation marks?

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual expression is "he is suffering from a high-grade fever."

In this expression the word "grade" is used in the following sense:

Grade: A particular level of rank, quality, proficiency, intensity, or value.

Comment: I can't recall ever hearing anyone say "high-grade fever".  To my ears it's nonsense, since a high fever cannot be considered "high quality" or "high proficiency".

Comment: @HotLicks - "low-grade" fever, however, is correct, for a mild elevation over normal, say 100.6°.

Comment: If you google "high-grade fever" you can see it's a common expression.  Here's an example in a paper from the NIH (US National Institute for Health): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15166919 "Low-grade and high-grade fever at presentation of acute pulmonary embolism."

Comment: *High-grade fever* is a clinical term; it's correct, but only healthcare providers or medical researchers would ever use it, which is why it appears in your link— a scientific study from a national research institute— and not in everyday use, where most would speak of a *high fever* or *high temperature*.

Comment: I agree that a high fever is also a common term, I'm not suggesting it's wrong, though I've always used high-grade and low-grade fever and I'm not a healthcare worker or medical researcher.

Comment: @HotLicks But a fever could be considered "high intensity."

Answer (score 0):

Outside of clinical settings, I think it's unusual to distinguish grades of fever. So it would be most correct to speak either of *a fever* or *a high temperature* in casual use. But *temperature* is a long word, so I suspect that people got into the habit of replacing it with *fever*. But the *high* modifier still sticks around in their mind, resulting in the redundant *high fever*.

This type of transformation results in many redundant phrases. It's very common when one of the words is an acronym or initialism, as in *PIN number* and *ATM machine*.

Comment: Fever is an *elevated body temperature*. Since there are degrees of elevation (would you rather fall from a two story window or a 20 story window?), *high fever* is not a redundancy.

Comment: But do lay people who say _high fever_ actually mean a higher degree? Is there such a thing as a _normal fever_, to which _high fever_ would be compared?

Comment: If they say _high fever_ when it's just 100, it sounds like they use it for any fever?

Comment: The issue is whether they use it to mean something different from just a fever in general.

Comment: All you did was say that people use the phrase _high fever_, which I never denied. You didn't say how it differs from _high temperature_. BTW, I also remember my mother saying that I had a temperature, meaning that I had a fever. We obviously don't use these words with their literal meanings.